# How to use @ElementCollection for Set<Integer> mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have 2 tables. `report_id` is PK. `animals_in_area` doesn't have a PK key.

I need to check is an `animal_id` in the `animal_report` by given `report_id` and `report_date`.
It seems like a simple task, but can I somehow describe a field `Set<Integer> adimalIds` in the `animal_report` class, mapped to the requested area?
I tried `@ElementCollection` + `@CollectionTable`, but it automatically maps `report_id` to `area_id`, because of `@Id` annotation.

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "animals_in_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "area_id"))
@Column(name = "animal_id")
private Set<Integer> adimalIds = new HashSet<>();
```

I want to use `criteriaBuilder.isMember(animalIdRequest, adimalIds)` in DTO.

What is the classic way? Join and get Set ?

```
               animal_report                                 animals_in_area
    ---------------------------------                      -------------------
    report_id | report_date | area_id                      area_id | animal_id  
    ---------------------------------                      -------------------
        1     |  01.01.2020 |  100                           100   |   1001
        2     |  01.01.2020 |  101                           100   |   1002
                                                             100   |   1003
                   .....                                     101   |   1002
                                                             101   |   1004
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "animal_report")
public class AnimalReport implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "report_id")
  private Long reportId;

  @Column(name = "report_date")
  private LocalDate reportDate;

  @Column(name = "area_id")
  private Integer areaId;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "animal_report")
public class AnimalReport implements Serializable {

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "animals_in_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "area_id", referencedColumnName = "area_id"))
  @Column(name = "animal_id")
  private Set<Integer> animalIds = new HashSet<>();

  // ...
}
```

You have to use `referencedColumnName` because the `animals_in_area.area_id` column refered to not primary key column of the `animal_report` table.